# Functions from MATLAB to XCode

Tags: ios, function, matlab

Essentially what I'm trying to do, is turn the following function:

```
function [template, mask] = createiristemplate(eyeimage_filename)
```

into a form useable by Xcode.  I've spent several hours poring over the internet, and have yet to find a clean way to make it work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Xcode, the mac IDE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode

According to wikipedia, this software can support the following languages:
C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Java, AppleScript, Python and Ruby

So the only way, is to use matlab coder, it is a matlab tool to convert matlab code in C or C++ :
http://www.mathworks.fr/products/matlab-coder/index.html

But it is an expansive toolbox.